# Subselect in SQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, subquery

I have a problem with writting trigger.
I have a table `tng_goods` with this columns:

```
id, name, parent_id, client_balance, sort
```

If the parent_id = 0 than this good does not a child of other good, if parent_id <> 0 than the good has a parent which located in this table.

---

For example:

```
id  name    parent_id   client_balance  sort 
1   reebok      0            10          1 
2   size:36     1            5           1 
3   size:37     1            200         1 
4   size:38     1            150         1 
5   adidas      0            0           5 
6   size:35     5            5           1 
7   size:37     5            3           5 
8   size:38     5            63          5
```

OK: The goal is change client_balance for parent goods after every change in table: insert, update, delete.
To achive, I write a sql query:

```
    UPDATE tng_goods tg SET tg.client_balance = (SELECT m FROM (SELECT MIN(client_balance) m, parent FROM tng_goods t GROUP BY parent ) chld WHERE tg.id = chld.parent),
tg.client_reserved = (SELECT m FROM (SELECT MIN(client_reserved) m, parent FROM tng_goods t GROUP BY parent ) chld WHERE tg.id = chld.parent),
tg.service_balance = (SELECT m FROM (SELECT MIN(service_balance) m, parent FROM tng_goods t GROUP BY parent ) chld WHERE tg.id = chld.parent)
WHERE tg.parent = 0;
```

However, when I use the trigger, I got an error:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'tng_goods' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

After, I read that in this case there is an recursive error. Therefore, I changed the query:

```
client_balance  = (SELECT m FROM (SELECT MIN(client_balance) m, parent FROM tng_goods t GROUP BY parent) chld WHERE id = chld.parent);
client_reserved = (SELECT m FROM (SELECT MIN(client_reserved) m, parent FROM tng_goods t GROUP BY parent ) chld WHERE id = chld.parent);
service_balance = (SELECT m FROM (SELECT MIN(service_balance) m, parent FROM tng_goods t GROUP BY parent ) chld WHERE id = chld.parent);
```

Also got an error:

```
This request has not been fulfilled: "CREATE DEFINER =` pl` @ `localhost` TRIGGER` GoodDelete` AFTER DELETE ON `tng_goods` FOR EACH ROW client_balance = (SELECT m FROM (SELECT MIN (client_balance) m, parent FROM tng_goods t GROUP BY parent) chld WHERE id = chld.parent); client_reserved = (SELECT m FROM (SELECT MIN (client_reserved) m, parent FROM tng_goods t GROUP BY parent) chld WHERE id = chld.parent); service_balance = (SELECT m FROM (SELECT MIN (service_balance) m, parent FROM tng_goods t GROUP BY parent) chld WHERE id = chld.parent); "
A MySQL: # 1064 - You have an error in your request. Refer to the documentation for your version of MySQL for correct syntax near '= (SELECT m FROM (SELECT MIN (client_balance) m, parent FROM tng_goods t GROUP BY' at line 1
```

Are there any ways to do it?
P.S Use MySql 5.7

Comment: You cannot update tables in their own triggers.

Comment: If this is a MySQL question please untag "Sql-Server".